# How to make Lichess local analysis utilize more cpu and memory?

Tags: engines, performance, lichess

I get around x12 faster evaluation when I run Stockfish myself, so I checked my utilization when running local analysis (Chromium and Firefox) and saw that it just utilizes one thread and few megabytes of memory.

So I am looking for a solution to make it fully utilize my hardware. Any ideas?

---

### EDIT:

**TL;DR** Issue was user-agent specific, doesn't work on Chromium/Ubuntu.

Comment: This is a feature question and as such generally off-topic. Please consider posting your question on the [Q&A section](https://lichess.org/qa) of lichess itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The menu for the analysis board has sliders for CPUs and memory (see screenshot below). Have you tried adjusting those? Maybe whether they actually work or not depends on which browser you are using. If they don't, I think this question would be best suited for the [Lichess feedback forum](https://lichess.org/forum/lichess-feedback), since it might be a bug.

[image: Screenshot of Lichess analysis board menu]

Comment: Which OS are you on? I don't have those sliders.

Comment: Chrome on OS X 10.10. I'll try Linux or Windows later for comparison.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu, no sliders.

Comment: @ferit, I just tried it on CentOS Linux 7.4 with Chrome Version 63. The sliders are there and moving the slider does affect CPU usage as expected. Maybe it's not supported by Chromium, or at least the version you are using? The process that actually uses the CPU is called nacl_helper, and apparently it's a feature that can be disabled in Chrome. I recommend investigating more along those lines.

Comment: I think you are right, I am going to solve the mystery with the help of this hint. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm I think the issue is the old Chromium. Apt installation installed a very old Chromium version I think, which doesn't have NAtive CLient. I'll let you know when I verify it.

Comment: No, it's not old. `Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)`

Comment: And yes, using Chrome, I got those options.